# Insert with select max fail in sql for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

When use a bunch of INSERT statements as below it takes forever :

```
INSERT INTO my_table ( col1, col2, id_col) VALUES ('val1', 'val1', (select max(my_table_ID) from my_table)+1);
```

If I run one by one and commit then it works fine. What is the reason?
I know sequence should be used in production. But I am writing this to insert few rows in toad.

Comment: Why don't you use an Oracle Sequence object instead?

Comment: Bad, bad practice. Concurrence will cause you troubles with this approach. Should use a sequence instead!

Comment: If I am Right then u r trying to create a serial number with each insert?

Answer (score 2):

may be

```
INSERT INTO my_table ( col1, col2, id_col) 
VALUES ('val1', 'val1', (select max(my_table_ID)+1 from my_table));
```

or in pl/sql block

```
declare
v_max number(10);
begin
select max(my_table_id) + 1 into v_max
  from my_table;
insert into my_table ( col1, col2, id_col) 
values ('val1', 'val1', v_max);
end;
/
```

but, i don't know you task...
may be used sequence + trigger before insert?